# Why does IsIterableContainingInOrder Hamcrest matcher fail to work with arrays?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I am obviously confused about how to use Hamcrest's `IsIterableContainingInOrder` to verify List equality beyond just using `.equals()`. I'd like to see Hamcrest's helpful messages in my reports.

Why are the tests below failing to even compile? Some of them are more counter-intuitive than others, at least for me. I get, I think, the general principle that the type parameter will be inferred to what I pass to a method with a varargs signature so it will consider arrays of T as varargs of T and so will generate a Matcher based on T and not on array of T, iterable of T, or anything like that.

I could use an explanation, please, as to why some of the lines that are most intuitive actually fail to even compile.

Particularly:

- 3 and 4 show the asymmetry of array/List
- 5 and 6 show that I can look in a List and not in an array (?)

The compiler warning on the line marked as such is even more mysterious to me.

---

```
@org.junit.Test
public void testTest() {
  String string1 = "A";
  String string2 = "B";
  String string3 = "C";

  List<String> list1 = Lists.newArrayList(string1, string2, string3);
  List<String> list2 = Lists.newArrayList(string1, string2, "C");

  String[] array1 = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
  String[] array2 = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) The assertion after this comment line DOES NOT COMPILE
  // Assert.assertThat(array2, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(array1));
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) The assertion after this comment line DOES NOT COMPILE
  // Assert.assertThat(list2, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(list1));
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) The assertion after this comment line SUCCEEDS
  Assert.assertThat(list2, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(array1));
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 4) The assertion after this comment line DOES NOT COMPILE + HAS WARNING
  // Assert.assertThat(array2, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(list1));
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 5) The assertion after this comment line DOES NOT COMPILE
  // Assert.assertThat(array2, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(string1));
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 6) The assertion after this comment line COMPILES but fails
  Assert.assertThat(list2, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(string1));
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 7) The assertion after this comment line COMPILES and succeeds
  Assert.assertThat(list2,
      IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(string1, string2, string3));
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

---

#### Copious amounts of astonishment. :(

---

PS I realise all of the astonishment comes from my own ignorance and nothing else. I should brush up on Generics, type inference, varargs, etc. I could really use a thorough explanation on this, and I would probably refer back to it a few times going forward.

PPS I *did* try to read the code first but look at it for a sec... ;) Not for the feint of heart:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Factory
public static <E> Matcher<Iterable<? extends E>> contains(final Matcher<? super E> itemMatcher) {
    return contains(new ArrayList<Matcher<? super E>>(asList(itemMatcher)));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the aswers... hopefully correct ones :)

```
// 1) The assertion after this comment line DOES NOT COMPILE
// Assert.assertThat(array2, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(array1));
```

This one does doesn't compile, because arrays don't implement Iteratable.

```
// 2) The assertion after this comment line DOES NOT COMPILE
// Assert.assertThat(list2, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(list1));
```

For this to work, list2 should be a `List<List<String>>`, as contains only verifies that the iteratable contains the item that is passed

```
// 3) The assertion after this comment line SUCCEEDS
Assert.assertThat(list2, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(array1));
```

Passes because array1 is taken as a vararg.

```
// 4) & 5)
```

Same as 1

```
// 6) The assertion after this comment line COMPILES but fails
Assert.assertThat(list2, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(string1));
```

Contains expects ***all*** the items in the collection, not just a subset.

```
// 7)
```

Similar as 3, but with each item passed.

Comment: Dude, thank you **so** much for this. I _really_ appreciate it. Now that you explained it, it makes sense...